# Error with shell script to run Racket program in interactive mode

Tags: shell, racket

I made a shell script that receives a racket file as a parameter and uses it to run the command below to execute the file and stay in interactive mode.

```
racket -i -e '(enter! "filename.rkt")'
```

The thing is, when I run the script the command above is executed without the last single quote, which generates an error message.

I've tried putting more characters at the end of the command (inside the script) to see if it was just ignoring the last character, but it didn't work.

Here is my script:

```
# rkt.sh

if [ "$#" -ne 1 ]; then
    echo "Not enough parameters!"
else
    option=\''(enter! "'$1'")'\'
    racket -i -e "$path"
fi
```

After running the command:

```
rkt test.rkt
```

Here's the error displayed by the racket program:

```
Welcome to Racket v7.0.
'(enter! "test.rkt")
string::21: read-syntax: expected an element for quoting "'", found end-of-file
  context...:
   reader-error12
   read-undotted
   read-syntax
```

But when I echo the script's variable *option*, it prints the desired result:

```
'(enter! "test.rkt")'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way of writing what I think you have in mind in Racket, without going through Bash. Just `chmod +x` the file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env racket
#lang racket/base

(require racket/cmdline)

(define file
  (command-line
   #:usage-help "start a Racket REPL inside the module <file>"
   #:args (file)
   file))

(void (write-string (banner)))

(define ns (make-base-namespace))
(parameterize ([current-namespace ns])
  (eval '(require racket/init racket/interactive))
  (eval `(enter! ,file))
  (read-eval-print-loop))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! So, do I need to put this code inside the racket code or is it a separated file that I'll use to start my racket code?

Comment: @PedroPontes If you save this code as "repl-inside.rkt" and want to enter "my-module.rkt", you would do something like `./repl-inside.rkt my-module.rkt`.

Comment: Well, it actually works! Sorry for the delay to answer and thanks for the help! I'll mark this as solved but I still am curious about what is happening with my code...

Answer (score 1):

Single quotes in Scheme implementations and descendants like Racket is used for literal data and you don't pair them.

The error message comes because it has read `'(enter! "test.rkt")` and evaluated that to `(enter! "test.rkt")`, though you have the standard Racket printing mode which doesn't show tha value rather a value that would evaluate to that value. Thus `'(enter! "test.rkt")`. After this it has read `'` but instead of getting what is quoted the data ends there. `'x` is valid `'` isn't.

I'm guessing this is what you want:

```
#/bin/sh

if [ "$#" -ne 1 ]; then
    echo "Not enough parameters!"
else
    option="(enter! \"$1\")"
    racket -i -e "$option"
fi
```

While you get it to load the file the defintions it may create doesn't seem to be available. Thus being in interactive mode after it has done its thing doesn't provide much functionality.

Comment: You're right, I forgot about how Racket evaluate single quotes... The code you wrote works but like you said it doesn't load the definitions for the interactive mode. Funny thing is that I had a working script on my computer just like this one, but after reinstalling the OS it got lost and now I can't figure out what to do :p. Thanks for the answer!